# Firefox Won't Fill Height for Table Layout

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I'm using a table layout for my website.  It's working in IE and Chrome, even IE 8 perfectly.  My entire website is in one table with three cells.  The top navbar, the content, and the bottom footer navbar.  The table's width and min-height is set to 100%, and the middle cell is set to height: auto.  This makes the footer get pushed to at least the bottom of the window, and if there is enough content the footer is painlessly pushed farther along with the content.

But Firefox won't make the middle cell's height fill to reach the table's min-height of 100%.
Here is what it looks like in Internet Explorer and Chrome (working):

[image: Internet Explorer is working]
[image: Chrome is working]

but in Firefox the middle cell's height isn't filling (not working):

[image: Firefox Table's Middle Cell won't Fill]

Here is my CSS:

```
<style>
#tablecontainer{
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%; 
}

.table-panel {
    display: table;
}
.table-panel > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-panel > div.fill {
    height: auto;
}




/* Unimportant styles just to make the demo looks better */
#top-cell {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:aqua;
}
#middle-cell {
  /* nothing here yet */
  background-color:purple;
}
#bottom-cell {
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}




body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="tablecontainer" class="table-panel">
        <div id="top-cell">
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </div>

    <div id="middle-cell" class="fill">
        <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-cell">
        <nav>
            <p>I'm the footer!</p>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's a fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/mmgftmyr/ It is completely accurate, the fiddle will work in Chrome and Internet Explorer but not Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem exists in the following styles:

```
#tablecontainer {
  min-height: 100%;  /* change min-height to height */
  width: 100%;
}
.table-panel {
  display: table;
}
```

`min-height: 100%` property doesn't work properly with `min-height` always. Change `min-height` to `height` and it will work.

***Note***: `HTML` tables have special behavior with height. If you specify `height` for a `table` or and element having `display: table` and its content doesn't fit in then its height will be increased automatically according to the content. So we can always use `height` instead of `min-height` with tables.

```css
#tablecontainer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-panel {
  display: table;
}
.table-panel > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-panel > div.fill {
  height: auto;
}

/* Unimportant styles just to make the demo looks better */
#top-cell {
  height: 50px;
  background-color:aqua;
}
#middle-cell {
  /* nothing here yet */
  background-color:purple;
}
#bottom-cell {
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="tablecontainer" class="table-panel">
  <div id="top-cell">
    <nav>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="middle-cell" class="fill">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bottom-cell">
    <nav>
      <p>I'm the footer!</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox, `min-height` is not interpreted on `display: table;` instead of using `min-height` use `height:100%;`

```
#tablecontainer{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lr0esn4/3/)